How do I get sveltekit +page.server.ts data into a svelte component?
I have a svelte component that displays a form using https://superforms.rocks and is setup as follows:
routes/
├─ blog/
├── +page.server.ts
├── +page.svelte
├── component.svelte

My experience is that the load function in +page.server.ts returns data to +page.svelte that is accessible via the $page store. But I need component.svelte to get data from +page.server.ts since +page.svelte is empty on rendered and requires user input to determine what data to display in component.svelte
How can this be accomplished? It's just not clear to me how component.svelte can get data from the server based on input from +page.svelte

The $page store is not the default way to get data, the primary way is the data prop of the page component. The store is mainly useful for nested components (so you don't have to pass data down via props).
There also is the form prop that is used to receive data in response to form actions. This is the main way to respond to user input via forms.
Though how/whether this should be used depends on what exactly the input is, e.g. it can also be a good approach to set URL search parameters (this happens automatically when using a form with method="get"). When doing this, the load function then can read those parameters from the url and respond accordingly. Having the data in the URL makes it possible to reload the page, bookmark or share it.

Thank you for your reply. I would like to use the $page store but when +page.svelte is rendered, the load method in +page.server.ts returns an empty form in $page since the data is read-only. The user will need to select a data item on +page.svelte which should then return from the server a detailed response of the selected data item and then be rendered in component.svelte. But that doesn't happen though because $page still contains the empty form from when +page.svelte was first rendered

The store is always read-only, you have to update form via form actions or data via navigation/invalidation which triggers load again. Please read the linked documentation on data loading and form actions, there are examples there as well.

For viewing a data item, I would use a separate route with a parameter (see routing/loading). The page with the items would just navigate on selection/render links to the various items.
